# React Redirect Hook Infinte Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I don't know the reason but if I try use the Navigate Hook to redirect to a specific path when my desktop changes mode, it dives into a sort of "infinite loop "  in the browser:

> history.ts:633 Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from
> hanging. See https://crbug.com/1038223. Command line switch
> --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection
>
> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.
> This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but
> useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the
> dependencies changes on every render.

[image]

My App.js

```
import "./App.scss";
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMediaQuery } from "./hooks/MediaQuery"; 
import Desktop from "./Pages/Desktop/Desktop";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path="*"
            element={
              useMediaQuery(750) ? (
                <Desktop replace to="/" />
              ) : (
                <Navigate replace to="/m" />
              )
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is an unconditional redirect loop is created in mobile views, from `"*"` to `"/m"` which is matched by `"*"` and the `Navigate` component is rendered again.

To stop this you might consider moving the redirect into a component lifecycle and only redirect if not already on `"/m"`. Here's a basic implementation using a `useEffect` hook in the media query hook.

```
import { useNavigate, useMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useMediaQueryRedirect = (width) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const isMobileMatch = useMatch("/m");

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkWidth = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth < width && !isMobileMatch) {
        navigate("/m");
      }
      if (window.innerWidth >= width && isMobileMatch) {
        navigate("/");
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", checkWidth, { passive: true });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", checkWidth, { passive: true });
    };
  }, [isMobileMatch, navigate, width]);
};
```

Create a layout route to use the hook and render the appropriate nested routes.

```
import { Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const MediaLayout = () => {
  useMediaQueryRedirect(750);

  return <Outlet />;
};

...

return (
  ...
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<MediaLayout />}>
      <Route path="/*" element={/* Main component routes */} />
      <Route path="/m/*" element={/* Mobile component routes */} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
  ...
);
```

[image: Edit react-redirect-hook-infinte-loop]

Comment: I wonder if is it possible to force the initial render path (without the hook  resize event)  with a specific query like "/?param=value".  I tried with the "onLoad " event but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @helloB Do you mean *other than* manually adding that queryString param when navigating to the app initially?

Comment: Yes. I mean the root address  '/'  must always be forced to include  a queryString like "?cover=value"  where value will be taken from a default value on the central Store

Comment: @helloB Some root component within the router could test if the current path matches `"/"` and inject the required queryString params if they are missing. The [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook would be helpful for this.

Comment: thanks.  Actually it works! I've Created a fucntion that retrieve/create  the query string value and then inject it in the  search: `?${createSearchParams(searchParams)}`, .  The problem  is it only triggers on the "resize" event! I've tried to add a new event "load" the calls the same same function but it doesn't work ! So everytime the user loads the page for the first time it doesn't navigate to the proper queryString url

Comment: @helloB I guess I could have provided a stronger hint. The `useSearchParams` returns also a function that works like `navigate` function but specifically for the queryString part of the URL. Use a `useEffect` hook to run this additional logic and issue the navigation action to update the URL.